# mod_rewrite, clean URLs, and GET parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, get

first I want to apologise profusely - I searched dozens of questions and I'm still at a complete loss (self-learner at a non-profit with limited knowledge of PHP).

I have a URL like this `http://www.welcomedesk.org/index.php?lang=en&page=home`
(all links redirect to index.php)

I would like it to show like `http://www.welcomedesk.org/en/home`

I have a mod_rewrite with this:
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

It's working! But I don't know what to do with my usual menu links? They are all subject to this function:

```
function redoUrl($addvalues = array())
{
$query = '?';

$keysnew = array_keys($addvalues);
$myget = $_GET;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($addvalues); $i++)
{
    $myget[$keysnew[$i]] = $addvalues[$keysnew[$i]];
}

$keys = array_keys($myget);
$i = 0;
//echo('<pre>'.print_r($addvalues).'</pre>');

foreach($myget as $get_param)
{
    if('' <>$get_param)
    {
        if ($query <> '?') { $query .= '&'; }
        $query .= $keys[$i] . '=' . $get_param;     
    }
    $i++;
}

return basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).$query;
}
```

Do I need to change this function? Do I need to hand-rewrite all of my links?

Furthermore, the files are named `$page_$lang.inc.php` and inserted to populate content, everything is situated in the main folder, but when I access `/en/home` it assumes that the new folder is /en/ and no longer finds anything. The mod_rewrite seems to forget that /en/ was a GET parameter and just loses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to change it so it's not using `$query`. Something like:

```
$uri = '';

$keysnew = array_keys($addvalues);
$myget = $_GET;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($addvalues); $i++)
{
    $myget[$keysnew[$i]] = $addvalues[$keysnew[$i]];
}

$keys = array_keys($myget);
$i = 0;
//echo('<pre>'.print_r($addvalues).'</pre>');

foreach($myget as $get_param)
{
    if('' <>$get_param)
    {
        $uri = $uri . '/' . $get_param;
    }
    $i++;
}

return basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).$uri;
}
```

Comment: @user3119486 Try removing the `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).` part